# restricting char set using regex in java

Tags: java

Basically i am trying to restrict a user not to input characters that are not allowed in username box. i found that this could be implement by `String.matches()`

```
String UcharSet = "[a-zA-Z0-9-~!@#().]+";
boolean UMORN = "Username.is@example.com".matches(UcharSet);
if(UMORN != true)
    UNotAllowedCharEC = "0x00000030";
```

as you can see i have string of characters to be allowed in my username box but somehow when i input `@` it return false although i have it in my allowed string list.

and do tell should i add any other characters to be allowed for my username box.

Comment: I tried it and `UMORN` is `true` for me.
Regarding additional characters, you may want to include underscore `_` as well.

Comment: i just need to assign `"0x00000030" to UNotAllowedCharEC` if the user input a restricted character, so am i doing the right way?

Comment: The code seems to be working fine. Just one advice, there is no point in comparing boolean variables with boolean literals in conditions. You can just write if( !UMORN).

Comment: **Don't** use regex to validate an email address. See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and '@' results in true.  You problem probably lies elsewhere.

[image: Valid]

Comment: oh i get the point now, actually i had the username sent from a client browser, which if you input `@` it converts it to `%40` in the air which i didn't had the `%` in my allowed list, and i was getting the error. now can you tell me how to allow @ here in my condition

Comment: URLDecoder.decode(str, "utf-8");

This will turn the %40 into @